# Problems getting Squirrelmail and passenger working on apache

Tags: apache-2.2, phusion-passenger, squirrelmail

I'm trying to have a setup where I want to run a squirrelmail and Passenger on the same apache server, having a url point to squirrelmail and everything else handled by passenger. I've gotten so far that both squirrelmail and passenger will run fine by themselves but when passenger is running it handles *all* urls.

So far I've tried using Alias and Redirect to point a webmail/ url to squirrelmails directory but that does not work.

Here is my httpd.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName not.my.real.server.name
  DocumentRoot /var/www/sinatra/public
  # Does not work:
  #Redirect webmail/ /usr/share/squirrelmail/
  #<Directory /usr/share/squirrelmail>
  #  Require all granted
  #</Directory>
  <Directory /var/www/sinatra/public>
    Order  allow,deny
    Allow  from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

apache2.conf has these files added for passenger, other than this I have not made any changes from the standard Ubuntu Server 12.04 installation of apache:

```
# passenger config
  LoadModule passenger_module /home/kenneth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.15/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
  PassengerRoot /home/kenneth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.15
  PassengerRuby /home/kenneth/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p194/ruby
```

The passanger config.ru file:

```
require './index'
run Sinatra::Application
```

Comment: Could you please provide your Apache config for passenger?

Comment: @quanta Done. I have only added the lines to apache2.conf as was instructed by the passenger install script. For good measure I have included the config.ru file as well. It is a fresh install so not much has been changed.

Comment: Do you have only one domain and you want `domain.com/webmail` go to squirrelmail and `domain.com/sinatra` go to your Rails app?

Comment: @quanta Yes, only one domain. Ideally I would like domain.com/webmail to go to squirrelmail and the rest of domain.com to go to the app. However if domain.com/sinatra will get both working I can be happy with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName not.my.real.server.name
    DocumentRoot /var/www

    Alias /webmail "/usr/share/squirrelmail"
    <Directory /usr/share/squirrelmail>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/sinatra>
        RackBaseURI /sinatra
        PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot On
        PassengerAppRoot /var/www/sinatra
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

---

**UPDATE**

I think that we can tell Rails to ignore particular URL by turning off the [`PassengerEnabled`](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_passengerenabled_lt_on_off_gt):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName not.my.real.server.name
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sinatra/public

    <Directory /var/www/sinatra/public>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all         
    </Directory>

    Alias /webmail "/usr/share/squirrelmail"
    <Location /webmail>
        PassengerEnabled off
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Give it a try!

Comment: Since it is a sinatra app RailsBaseURI was changed to RackBaseURI and I just needed to point the paths to where the config.ru file was stored and it works. Thank you. I have edited your answer with the tweaks that made it work.

Comment: @Kenneth: thank you. I'm not familiar with sinatra app. Updated my answer.

Comment: That is it, spot on. Sinatra now handles all URIs except webmail/. Thanks for going the extra distance. If I could upvote twice, I would :)